# I would like to add few items to every item of a vector in R

Tags: r

I have 2 vectors.

1 for services:

```
services <- c('service1', 'service2')
```

1 for cities:

```
cities <- c('city1','city2','city3','city4','city5','city6')
```

I would like to combine them to create a list like this:

```
c('city1 service1', 'city1 service2','city2 service1', 'city2 service2','city3 service1', 'city3 service2','city4 service1', 'city4 service2','city5 service1', 'city5 service2','city6 service1', 'city6 service2')
```

I guess I have to use apply, but I can't get the result. Sorry for the silly question.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, sorry the mentioned post solves the same problem

Answer (score 2):

```
services <- c('service1', 'service2')
cities <- c('city1','city2','city3','city4','city5','city6')
n <- length(cities)
paste(cities, rep(services, each=n))

 [1] "city1 service1" "city2 service1" "city3 service1" "city4 service1" "city5 service1"
 [6] "city6 service1" "city1 service2" "city2 service2" "city3 service2" "city4 service2"
[11] "city5 service2" "city6 service2"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `expand.grid` then `paste`

```
services <- c('service1', 'service2')
cities <- c('city1','city2','city3','city4','city5','city6')
tmp <- expand.grid(services, cities) 

paste(tmp$Var2, tmp$Var1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
services <- c('service1', 'service2')
cities <- c('city1','city2','city3','city4','city5','city6')
df <- expand.grid(services, cities)
res <- paste(df[[1]], df[[2]])
res
```